# Calculate the oscillation of two dataframes

Tags: python, database, pandas

I have two dataframes. One represents the minimum values ​​and the other the maximum values. As below:

```
      df_Min = pd.DataFrame({'IDsensor': [1, 2, 3], 
                            'Sensor_SYS1_Min': [54, 55, 75],
                            'Sensor_SYS2_Min': [320, 315, 400]})


      df_Max = pd.DataFrame({'IDsensor': [1, 2, 3], 
                             'Sensor_SYS1_Max': [55, 60, 80],
                             'Sensor_SYS2_Max': [320, 320, 800]})
```

I would like to calculate the variation between them. That is, the oscillation between the maximum value and the minimum value.

I tried to do the following operation (This operation is incorrect):

```
      df_Oscillation = abs(df_Max - df_Min)
```

I would like the output to be like this:

```
      df_Oscillation = pd.DataFrame({'IDsensor': [1, 2, 3], 
                                     'Sensor_SYS1_Oscillation': [1, 5, 5],
                                     'Sensor_Oscillation': [0, 5, 400]})
```

Comment: this one looks like you can subtract after setting ID as index and then do `df.abs()` :  
 `df_Max.set_index('IDsensor').sub(df_Min.set_index('IDsensor')).abs().reset_index()` :)

Answer (score 2):

Two key changes: use an index and use the abs method

```
df_Min.set_index('IDsensor', inplace=True)
df_Max.set_index('IDsensor', inplace=True)

(df_Max - df_Min).abs()
```

Setting the index like this allows the dataframes to align on the sensor id for subtraction even if they are created with the IDs in different orders. Using the `.abs` method allows operations to be handled efficiently over the dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

This worked when I tried it: `abs(df_Max.subtract(df_Min))`
This also worked: `df_Max.subtract(df_Min).abs()`

```
import pandas as pd
df_Min = pd.DataFrame({'IDsensor': [1, 2, 3], 
                      'Sensor_SYS1': [54, 55, 75],
                      'Sensor_SYS2': [320, 315, 400]})

df_Max = pd.DataFrame({'IDsensor': [1, 2, 3], 
                        'Sensor_SYS1': [55, 60, 80],
                        'Sensor_SYS2': [320, 320, 800]})

def print_df(title, df):
  return print(f'{title}\n{df}\n')

print_df('df_Min', df_Min)
print_df('df_Max', df_Max)
print_df('df_Oscillation', df_Max.subtract(df_Min).abs())
```

Comment: It also didn't work for me. A dataframe full of 'NaN' results. Do you know what it can be?

Comment: You changed your column names. Use df.rename to make them match.